# Angular Material theme not changing colors

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular 1.4.3 and Angular Material 0.10.0 and I am trying to use the build-in theme "green" for my app. However, even after I have done the below, the colors remain to be the default indigo:

```
 angular.module('myApp','ngMaterial'])
  .config(['$mdThemingProvider', function($mdThemingProvider){
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('green');
    $mdThemingProvider.setDefaultTheme('green');
  }])
```

It would be helpful if this pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJYJGb could be  edited to make the theme work. I could then apply the same for my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you cannot specify the color name in the `.theme('default')`.

Here is the code which i have used to change the default color of my `md-toolbar`, [codepen](http://codepen.io/nrvarun/pen/VLgPxY).

We can change the default color of angular-material by using the themeprovider in this way :

```
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('green')
    .accentPalette('orange');
});
```

Hope it helps.

Here is the code which i took from your codepen and edited it:

```
.config(['$mdThemingProvider', function($mdThemingProvider){
$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
.primaryPalette('green');
```

`}])`

Now it is all green in color.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. I guess I didn't read the docs carefully enough.

Comment: @c05mic happy to help.

Comment: Codepen link is broken.